# download failed in ubuntu software

Tags: ubuntu

I tried to install TeXstudio from Ubuntu software, but download failed, and it shows me this message:

```
Unable to install TeXstudio as download failed:
E:http://mirror.serverloft.eu/ubuntu/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 lipqt5script5
amd64 5.12+dfsg-0ubuntu1 is not (yet) available 
(Temporary failure resolving 'mirror.serverloft.eu')
```

Comment: Have you checked the network connection on the system? Can you resolve any hosts? If you can't that would indicate that it's not working entirely or has a DNS issue. I can resolve the `mirror.serverloft.eu` from a system with a network connection so this is pointing to a problem with yours.

Comment: Why not download it from the official website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lipqt5script5 5.12+dfsg-0ubuntu1` isn't available on Ubuntu focal that's why you have received the `is not (yet) available` error. The available version is `5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1` here is the output of `apt policy libqt5script5`:

```
libqt5script5:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
```

You can install `texstudio` from [`ppa:sunderme/texstudio`](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Esunderme/+archive/ubuntu/texstudio) recommended by [the official website](https://www.texstudio.org/)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sunderme/texstudio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install texstudio
```